# Do we really need to do a system initialization to get Spartacus to work?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront, b2b

We have a B2B store running on 2105 and now we want to integrate spartacus on it. So, do we really need to do system initialization during installing spartacus (adding spartacussampledata) on the store?

How to install spartacus without system initialization?

Comment: You can use just update.

Comment: I did the update after adding the 'spartacussampledata' to bin/custom folder and in localextensions.xml. But the new catalog and site with 'spa' is not reflecting in Back office.

Comment: Did you try ant build before update? Did you check hac for extension?

Comment: Yes, I did "ant clean all" and in hac the extension is there.

Comment: Did you add config parameters for spartacus storefronts?

Comment: sorry, I am not getting you. can you please provide those config parameters?

Comment: Check the file /resource/installer/customconfig/custom.properties in spartacussampledata extension.

Answer (score 1):

Current [spartacussampledata.2105](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/releases/tag/storefront-4.2.0) not supporting update operation. I created working [extension](https://github.com/mkysoft/hybris-spartacussampledata) based on original one.

I created extensions' [system setup class](https://github.com/mkysoft/hybris-spartacussampledata/blob/main/spartacussampledata/src/de/hybris/platform/spartacussampledata/setup/impl/SpSampleDataSystemSetup.java) for update step.